# Running SSMS for SQL Server 2012 with multiple instances with different collation

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I already have **SQL Server 2012** `(collation: Latin1_General_CI_AS)` working happily on my machine. But I need to connect to an old database with different collation `(SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)`.
So, I installed another instance of **SQL Server 2012** with this collation. But I am not able to access this instance of SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS).

There is just one SSMS on my machine and whenever I try to connect to it, it connects to earlier instance of SQL Server 2012. How do I get SSMS connected to new instance of SQL Server?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to connect from local and not sure of instance name..You can try selecting the browser for more option in servernames and click on local servers as shown below.This will enumerate all the instances present in machine..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The new instance is likely not the default instance.  The default instance would be something like machinename\mssqlserver.  You can connect by using machinename.  Other instances need the name specified.  machinename\nondefaultinstancename.  SQL Browser service need to be running as the non default instance likely uses dynamic ports, unless you set it up to be static.

Since the instances are on the machine you are working on you do not need to worry about opening firewall ports.